# R Nest Loop Regressions

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop

I wish to estimate regression models for d1, d2, d3 and values of vs = 0 and = 1, this is a total of 6 regression models. However in my loop it only stores 3 and I do not know why?

```
library(dplyr)
    data(mtcars)

d1=sample_n(mtcars, 10)
d2=sample_n(mtcars, 10)
d3=sample_n(mtcars,10)

models = data.frame(model=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                    val=c(0,1,0,1,0,1),
                    coef=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

d = list(d1, d2,d3)
for(i in 1:length(d)) {
  for (j in 0:1) {
    data=d[[i]] %>% filter(vs == j)
    model=lm(cyl~disp,data=data)
    models[i, 3] = summary(model)$coefficients[2,1]
    
  }
}


################ store stderror too
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

d1=sample_n(mtcars, 10)
d2=sample_n(mtcars, 10)
d3=sample_n(mtcars,10)

models = data.frame(model=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                    val=c(0,1,0,1,0,1),
                    coef=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                    ste=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

d = list(d1, d2,d3)
for(i in 1:length(d)) {
  for (j in 0:1) {
    data=d[[i]] %>% filter(vs == j)
    model=lm(cyl~disp,data=data)
    models[i, 3] = summary(model)$coefficients[2,1]
    models[i, 4] = summary(model)$coefficients[2,2]
  }
}
```

Comment: @Onyambu i thought it was looping over i and j which would be 6 models...how do i modify?

Comment: Your value of `i` never exceeds the length of `d` which is `3`, so how do you expect `d[[i]]` to work outside of that?

Comment: @r2evans because the second loop isn't it looping i = 1 j = 0, 1; i = 2 j = 0, 1?

Comment: would it be easier to use `eg <- expand.grid(i = seq_along(d), j = 0:1) ; mapply(function(i, j) summary(lm(cyl ~ disp, data = filter(d[[i]], vs == j)))$coefficients[2,1], eg$i, eg$j)`?

Comment: Use `nlme::lmList`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a matrix to store the i,j index:

```
models = matrix(NA, 3, 2)
d = list(d1, d2,d3)
for(i in 1:length(d)) {
  for (j in 0:1) {
    data=d[[i]] %>% filter(vs == j)
    model =lm(cyl~disp,data=data)
    models[i,j+1] = summary(model)$coefficients[2,1]
  }
}
```

---

Also note that the same could be soved without explicitly using `for loops`:

```
library(tidyverse)
map(d, ~group_by(.x, vs)%>%summarise(m = lm(cyl~disp)$coef[2]))
```

---

To store everything from the model have:

```
lst(d1, d2, d3) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'data_name') %>%
  group_by(data_name, vs)%>%
  reframe(broom::tidy(summary(lm(cyl~disp))))

# A tibble: 12 × 7
   data_name    vs term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 d1            0 (Intercept)  3.19      1.63        1.95  0.190  
 2 d1            0 disp         0.0127    0.00507     2.51  0.128  
 3 d1            1 (Intercept)  2.79      0.781       3.57  0.0233 
 4 d1            1 disp         0.0127    0.00493     2.59  0.0610 
 5 d2            0 (Intercept)  3.39      0.909       3.73  0.0336 
 6 d2            0 disp         0.0120    0.00293     4.09  0.0264 
 7 d2            1 (Intercept)  1.80      0.488       3.69  0.0346 
 8 d2            1 disp         0.0180    0.00325     5.55  0.0115 
 9 d3            0 (Intercept)  5.72      0.763       7.51  0.00169
10 d3            0 disp         0.00548   0.00206     2.67  0.0561 
11 d3            1 (Intercept)  1.37      2.04        0.671 0.571  
12 d3            1 disp         0.0236    0.0151      1.57  0.258
```

lastly: in a for loop use:

```
models = list()
for(i in 1:length(d)) {
  sub_model = list()
  for (j in 0:1) {
    data=d[[i]] %>% filter(vs == j)
    model=lm(cyl~disp,data=data)
    sub_model [[j+1]]= summary(model)$coefficients
  }
  models[[i]] = sub_model
} 
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
              Estimate  Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.18765829 1.631370949 1.953975 0.1899134
disp        0.01274924 0.005072478 2.513415 0.1284864

[[1]][[2]]
              Estimate Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 2.78991368 0.78102439 3.572121 0.02333143
disp        0.01273958 0.00492694 2.585699 0.06095975


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
              Estimate  Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.38847344 0.908555730 3.729516 0.03358602
disp        0.01200143 0.002934268 4.090094 0.02641811

[[2]][[2]]
              Estimate  Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 1.79995297 0.488231213 3.686681 0.03459618
disp        0.01803584 0.003249465 5.550404 0.01153293


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
               Estimate  Std. Error  t value    Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 5.724008115 0.762501333 7.506883 0.001685022
disp        0.005477936 0.002055504 2.665008 0.056096805

[[3]][[2]]
             Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 1.3690760 2.04042916 0.6709745 0.5713482
disp        0.0236118 0.01507344 1.5664503 0.2577454
```

Comment: that doesn't work.

Comment: @bvowe sorry forgot that j starts from 0 and not 1. Try it out

Comment: @Oyambu thank you it works now, but how do I format it in the way I proposed? In my original models for example. I don't mean to be picky but it is so the next person knows which models and values of vs the coefscomes from

Comment: @bvowe its simple. the first row is for columns = vs, rows = data. eg the first row is d1, and vs=0, vs=1

Comment: ok but what if say you needed to store the intercept too? would you put that in models[i+1,j+1] or would you need to store it like ina a list?

Comment: @bvowe depending on how you want the results, you could store the results in a list of lists etc.. I would encourage you to learn the R containers and how to loop. Also note that you should be able to use tidyverse methods eg the second methods listed above

Comment: i added the example...so you are saying use a list to store each model output? i am learning now about lists

Answer (score 0):

When running an expansion of models like that, I like to start with `expand.grid` (filtering if there are infeasible combinations) and then `Map`ping over each row.

```r
eg <- expand.grid(i = seq_along(d), j = 0:1)
eg
#   i j
# 1 1 0
# 2 2 0
# 3 3 0
# 4 1 1
# 5 2 1
# 6 3 1
mapply(function(i, j) summary(lm(cyl ~ disp, data = filter(d[[i]], vs == j)))$coefficients[2,1], eg$i, eg$j)
# [1] 0.006389783 0.008036061 0.008431033 0.042496308 0.012565410 0.015597955
```

Since you're asking about saving multiple coefficients, it's often useful (especially for more complicated regressions that take time) to store the models separately.

```r
models <- Map(function(i, j) lm(cyl ~ disp, data = filter(d[[i]], vs == j)), eg$i, eg$j)
eg$intercept <- sapply(models, function(md) summary(md)$coefficients[1,1])
eg$disp <- sapply(models, function(md) summary(md)$coefficients[2,1])
eg
#   i j intercept        disp
# 1 1 0  5.398629 0.006389783
# 2 2 0  4.859899 0.008036061
# 3 3 0  4.858518 0.008431033
# 4 1 1 -1.122747 0.042496308
# 5 2 1  3.114896 0.012565410
# 6 3 1  2.724953 0.015597955
```

or grab a bunch of coefficients at once:

```r
## [,1:2] only because I just added those columns above
cbind(eg[,1:2], t(sapply(models, function(md) summary(md)$coefficients[,1])))
#   i j (Intercept)        disp
# 1 1 0    5.398629 0.006389783
# 2 2 0    4.859899 0.008036061
# 3 3 0    4.858518 0.008431033
# 4 1 1   -1.122747 0.042496308
# 5 2 1    3.114896 0.012565410
# 6 3 1    2.724953 0.015597955
```

Answer (score 0):

You only get 3 models because the loop is trying to store both the j=0 and j=1 subsets for i in models[i, 3] so the last one attempted overwrites the first leaving 3.  In addition there is a problem with coordinating the model, val and regression statistics so that the latter do not necessarily correspond.

Suggest instead that since you are using dplyr to also use `broom::tidy` and iterate `rowwise` through the input.  Also note that we used `set.seed` to make this reproducible,
and the `subset=` argument of `lm` to eliminate the need for a separate filter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
set.seed(123)

d <- list(d1 = sample_n(mtcars, 10),
          d2 = sample_n(mtcars, 10),
          d3 = sample_n(mtcars, 10))

g <- expand.grid(val = 0:1, model = names(d))[2:1]

g %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(lm(cyl ~ disp, d[[model]], subset = vs == val) %>% 
           tidy %>%
           select(estimate, std.error) %>%
           slice(2)
  ) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving

```
## ..snip some warnings about a perfect fit...
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  model   val estimate std.error
  <fct> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 d1        0 7.40e-18  1.26e-17
2 d1        1 2.31e- 2  3.83e- 3
3 d2        0 1.50e- 2  4.10e- 3
4 d2        1 1.36e-17  1.55e-17
5 d3        0 0         0       
6 d3        1 1.30e- 2  5.08e- 3
```